# jQuery animate fade in div from offscreen, keep centered for a certain amount of time and fade out again

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I've been googling for about an hour now and can't find a solution, so I'll ask here.

First of all, I'm new to jQuery, so please bear with me.

What I want to do:

I wanna have a div that "flies" from (left) off the screen to the middle of the screen, stays there for a few seconds and then flies out to the right, again off the screen (then it disappears altogether)

My problem is that I don't fully understand how I can center the div depending on the view-point.

This is what I had working so far

```
$('#flashes')
    .css('margin-left',-$(this).width())
    .animate({
         marginLeft: 0
    }, 1500)
    .delay(7000)
    .css('margin-right',-$(this).width())
    .animate({
      marginLeft: 5000 
    }, 1500, 
    function(){$('#flashes').remove();}
);
```

This worked great, as long as the size of my browser was right :D (hence I never stumbled upon the error until an hour ago)

The css (in case that would interfere):

```
#flashes {
    min-height: 30px; width: 960px;
}
```

What I tried: I tried replacing the marginLeft with complicated formulas or easy ones such as $(this).width() / 4 to let it start on 25% of the screen but this is all bullshit (as I found out on my own *g*). I simply want the div to slide in from nowhere, right to the middle and then be gone after 7 seconds.

**Edit**

```
$('#flashes')
  .css('margin-left',-$(this).width())
  .animate({
      'left': '50%',
      'margin-left': $(this).width() / 4
  }, 1500)
  .delay(7000)
  .css('margin-right',-$(this).width())
  .animate({
    marginLeft: $(window).width() 
  }, 1500, 
  function(){$('#flashes').remove();}
);
```

This works for fullscreen (1920*1200px) but not for half the screen anymore :(
I need to get the window-size into the "margin-left" formula, I guess.

But apart from that, this does exactly what I want.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NB74E/

Now you see, on the small screen-size it's not centered anymore. :(

Answer (score 0):

One method to achieve absolute center of a div (horizontal and vertical) depending on your viewport set these CSS proprietes (the width and height needs to be defined):

```
div {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top:-divHeight/2;
margin-left:-divWidth/2;
}
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/QuwPE/5/

Comment: Thanks, I should've mentioned that I don't want to use absolute positioning at all, as it interferes with the development-style built upon flex-boxes as well as the current production style that uses floating. **Also** the problem does not lie in the positioning but in the animation itself. I want this to start off-screen and then go right into the middle. Just positioning into the middle wouldn't be a problem, just use margin: 0 auto;

Comment: Try @jlansner solution, but put the second .animation() and .delay() in callback function of the first .animation() - like in the jsfiddle I've shared you.

Comment: Still not working, but thanks a lot for your time and efforts :)

Comment: If jQuery doesn't do the trick, try CSS animation. Here's some info about it: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/

Comment: Thank you, but CSS-Animation isn't really usable, because you can't delay the animation at a certain point. I've updated my initial question though.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(window).width()` to get the width of the browser, and then set the position based on that.

```
$('#flashes')
    .css('margin-left',-$(this).width())
    .animate({
         marginLeft: ($(window).width() - $(this).width()) / 2
    }, 1500)
    .delay(7000)
    .css('margin-right',-$(this).width())
    .animate({
      marginLeft: $(window).width() 
    }, 1500, 
    function(){$('#flashes').remove();}
);
```

Comment: Thank you, this doesn't work. It's still sticking to the left side of the page :(